# Couchdb bulk update specific property without _bulk_docs

Tags: couchdb, bulkupdate

First. I learned perform update by using _update function (But this work with only one document Id)

Seconds. We can use _bulk_docs to update bukl of documents. In this case, We have to load all documents, then modify it properties. This make very many queries.

Is there any ways to perform bulk update on 1 property on many documents ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in CouchDB to perform a partial update of the json doc without loading, modifying and saving the whole document.

If you run a recent version of CouchDB (2.X) you can reduce the number of queries by using the `_bulk_get` endpoint to fetch many docs at once, or by a POST to `_all_docs` with a `{"keys":[key1, key2, ..., keyN]}` as the body.

Comment: Bulk endpoit was available before 2.X (eg: 1.6.9)